# Tooltip in Datagrid, added from code-behind

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm new to wpf and im having trouble adding tooltips to my datagrid header from code-behind.

I need to use autogeneratecolumns on the datagrid which rules out xaml editing. All examples i could find involved som xaml editing.

I've tried to add it the DataGridTextColumn without succeding

```
private void dataGrid1_AutoGeneratedColumns(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridTextColumn item in dataGrid1.Columns)
        {
            ToolTip tooltip = new ToolTip();
            tooltip.Content = "Test";
            ToolTipService.SetToolTip(item, tooltip);
        }
    }
```

I can see that the ToolTip variable is set in the WPF visualizer but nothing shows in the datagrid.

Help!

Comment: Perhaps the accepted answer to this question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735573/unable-to-set-datagridcolumns-tooltip

Comment: I couldnt figure out how to change the tooltip value with that approach.

Answer (score 4):

I ended up using this approach:

```
    private void dataGrid1_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender,DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
            Style style = new Style(typeof(DataGridColumnHeader));
            Trigger trigger = new Trigger();
            trigger.Property = IsMouseOverProperty;
            trigger.Value = true;
            Setter setter = new Setter();
            setter.Property = ToolTipProperty;
            setter.Value = "Your tooltip";
            trigger.Setters.Add(setter);
            style.Triggers.Add(trigger);
            e.Column.HeaderStyle = style;

    }
```